# File Handling in c++ with classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, file-handling

The program is done in C++.

I am working on a program where I have multiple classes. For the sake of the question lets consider them "Class BaseA", Class Child1", "Class Child2". Both classes Child1 and Child2 inherits from BaseA.

Now i created multiple objects of classes Child 1 And Child2 And I have to store it in a file.
Which I have a done using write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj)).

Now the problem is how do I read from this file?
because the read function also takes an (size of object). and my file has different classes object store with different size in them how do i read this file properly and store it back in appropriate class objects.

Comment: If the objects are different sizes, then you need to store that size before you write the object. When reading it back, you read the size information first, so you know how many bytes to read to get the proper object back out of the file.

Comment: Before you go through the trouble of figuring it out, have you figured out, already, that you even ***can*** `write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj))` and get something meaningful? This only works in C++ if `obj` meets certain, strict, requirements. Do you know what these requirements are? Otherwise, you ***only think*** you actually wrote these objects to the file, but any attempt to read these objects back, in any shape, way, matter, or form, is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is about : **how can we know the actual type of the object output as a file?**

If the class type and size can be arbitrarily changed,
I recommend to **write the data header** with class information when writing object data.

The first thing you need to do is design the file format.

I suggest looking at a format of bitmap file as a simple example. The bitmap file consists of a header section and a data section. The header section contains information that the file is a bitmap and the file size.

What you can see from the example is that the design of a file format should include:

1. Information about the file type : so you can identify it's your file format(This is also called a File magic number.)
2. Information about the data : object type, object size, etc.. If you want to save multiple objects in one file, you need to know the start and end positions of the data.
3. Actual object data

In addition, if there is an inheritance structure of a class, it is recommended to design the file input/output function in association with the inheritance structure of the class.
(Example: calling the parent class's file IO function inside the child class's file IO function)